# What is the name of the table operation that standardizes the template structure?

Tags: join, datatable, standardization

I am struggling to find the proper term for the following table operation:

1. I take the cross product of all years (2018-2021 in our example) and companies (in the left table)
2. left join the original dataset to the newly created dataset (~template)

I aim to have all the years for all companies regardless of how many data points I have.

What would be the best definition to describe what I am doing?
Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: Your "cross product" is more typically called a "cross join". It is a mathematical "Cartesian product" ([ref.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product)). I don't think there is a single, concise term for what you are doing, overall. Maybe _"cross join used to fill gaps in a data set"_.

Comment: Yes, thanks, it is really a cross-join, good point!